# How to convert table column 'Into input field' and get input field value and id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data in the given table below. I would like the table cell convert into  an `<input/>` field, once I click on it. After that the the  `value` of `<input/>` and their `id` value send via `ajax` request.
Is it possible?

Here I have written some lines of code, but it return me the `value` of `inputfield`. But I also need `id`  of `table cell where I click`.

For example:

```
     <table class="table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
           102
          </td>
      <td data-editable id="102">
           Elex Jordan
          </td>
        </tr>
```

here is javascript

```
    <script>
    $('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function(){
     var $el = $(this);
     var $input = $('<input/>').val( $el.text() );
     $el.replaceWith( $input );
     var save = function(){
     var $p = $('<p data-editable />').text( $input.val() );
     $input.replaceWith( $p );
     var my=$input.val()

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
        url:"req.php",
        data:{my:my},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
          }   
       });
      };
       $input.one('blur', save).focus();
    });
    </script>
```

the value of `<input/>` coming. But i also need `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `attr` method on `$elm` to access its `id`

```
$el.attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use contenteditable attribute in your td tag or in -th-

```
<td contenteditable id="id" class="class" data-id="103">Testing</td>

<script>
var html_value = $('#id').html();
var id = $('#id').attr("data-id");
</script>
```